# Inconsistent UDEV behavior 'dev/video14'

Tags: usb, udev, symbolic-link

I am trying to write a udev rule that creates a symlink `/dev/video14` that points to the `/dev/video` index of my usb camera, so that I can map it to the same index consistently.

I currently have the following udev rule in the file `25-udev-myrule.rules`

```
KERNEL=="video[0-12]*", ATTRS{serial}=="75EF299F", SYMLINK+="video14"
```

and it works, but not consistently. If I power cycle my computer with the camera connected, sometimes the symlink will get created, and sometimes it won't. Is there something wrong with my udev rule?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will be significant in this context, but the glob expression `[0-12]` will only match 0, 1, or 2

Comment: I was thinking the same... the asterisk afterwards would allow for as many zeroes, ones or twos in sequence, i.e. 'video012012' would be matched. But 'video3', for example, wouldn't get matched. Try "video([1-9]|1[0-2])" to match any number in the range 1 to 12.

Comment: @nagelp is that correct? would that not be 110 to 912?

Comment: Interesting. Using the `[0-12]` expression that I have, it has mapped successfully in the past when the device was video10, or video8

Comment: @Rinzwind I think so. There is an "or" (|) between [1-9] (single digit numbers) and 1[0-2], i.e. 10, 11 or 12.

Comment: @jpb647 surprising. You can try `echo "video8" | grep -w 'video[0-12]*'` and `echo "video10" | grep -w 'video[0-12]*'`. The first won't get matched, the latter will.

Comment: One last comment for today: To test the regexp I proposed with 'grep -w', you'll have to escape the brackets and the pipe, i.e. `echo "video8" | grep -w 'video\([1-9]\|1[0-2]\)'` - not sure whether that's also necessary in udev rules though... that's always the part I find most confusing about regexps...

Comment: @nagelp udev uses *shell glob* patterns (with the addition of the `|` alternation operator) - not regexes. Think of it like a shell `case`. There's actually no mention of grouping in the udev manpage, so you may need to resort to 2 separate rules or perhaps `/dev/video[0-9]|/dev/video1[0-2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was related to @steeldriver's comment. Changing the glob expression from `KERNEL=="video[0-12]*"` to `KERNEL=="video[0-9]|video1[0-2]"`, helped the udev rule identify the video device more consistently. Lastly, I had a startup script that was being run, that made a call to `udevadm trigger`, which for some reason was causing my rule to not be applied consistently.

Removing the call to `udevadm trigger` and changing my udev rule syntax solved the problem.